# What real-life buildings are the Settlers of Catan Victory point cards based on?

Tags: catan

Every version of Settlers of Catan that I've played (all US Mayfair, editions 1-4) has had a "University" victory point card that is clearly the church of [Santa María del Naranco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Mar%C3%ADa_del_Naranco) in Oviedo, Spain. Are any of the other victory point cards based on real-life buildings?[image]

Comment: The veranda in the palace is very similar to the one in the University. As Santa Maria del Naranco doesn't actually have the veranda, I'm guessing that the real-life version of the palace might also not have the veranda, and might also be a stone building based on the construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chapel is a close depiction of the [Gol Stave Church in Oslo](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Gol_Stave_Church.jpg). The palace, I don't know.